# SAML not working, validator passes

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

We are setting up SSO with a custom SAML identity provider. The SAML validator passes just fine:

[image]

But then when we try to login, we get:

[image]

I can't see any error logs anywhere (login/history). The strangest thing is that we have a parallel setup with ADFS working perfectly.

I can't see any differences between our custom IdP and ADFS. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: You've uploaded the IdP's certificate? Is the SAML encrypted or just signed?

Comment: Yes, it's uploaded. Just signed.

Comment: Check the URL in the address bar for the Login Error page - if I remember correctly, it should give you more info. Also, you can paste the encoded SAML response into https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php and check the SAML assertion - that might give you a clue.

Comment: The address bar is: http://na15.salesforce.com/_nc_external/identity/saml/SamlError  (no extra info). Yes, we've been using the SAML debugger and it is all good....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue:

The SAML Validator accepts encoded + ziped responses, but SalesForce doesn't. It only accepts ***encoded*** tokens (no zip).

Please fix the validator so it matches the actual endpoint!

Comment: Forwarding this to the Identity team right now!

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on why you'd be providing a zipped SAML response...?

Comment: @metadaddy, can you show them this: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hk0FAAQ

Comment: @chuck: what was confusing was that the SAML Validator reads: _Enter your SAML response in base64-encoded, deflated and base64-encoded, or plain xml format into the field below, and click Validate._   I just assumed that it supported both. I don't need it. I don't expect very large tokens to be sent anyway. It didn't occur to me that the SF.COM endpoint only supported encoded. Makes sense?