# SAML Validation Error

Tags: saml

I am facing SAML validation issue as our URL gets appended with “_nc_external/identity/saml/SamIError".

[image: After providing company's global id and password instead of salesforce.com user id and password]

Also this issue is randomly generated for particular set of users, not always.
Can you explain me how to fix this issue?

Similar to issue posted by Eugenio Pace 
[SAML not working, validator passes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11230/saml-not-working-validator-passes)

Comment: What does the [SAML Login History](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_saml_login_history.htm&language=en_US) say?